# RewriteRule for redirecting old URL to new URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am not able to write RewriteRule for redirecting old URL to new URL:

**Old URL:** `http://www.hostname.com/hello.php`

**New URL:** `http://www.hostname.com/folder1/hello.php`

here `hello.php` is any dynamic name

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.hostname\.com$
RewriteRule ^/hello.php$ /folder1/hello.php [L,R=301]
```

- `RewriteCond` is to ensure this rewrite only happens on the specific domain name, remove if irrelevant
- `L` means any further rules will not be processed
- `R=301` means "Permanently moved"

If there are several filenames to redirect, you can alter the `RewriteRule` line to match multiple names:

```
RewriteRule ^/(hello|goodbye|welcome).php$ /folder1/$1.php [L,R=301]
```

Here `$1` is the first subpattern in parentheses, if there will be more, they will get subsequent numbers - `$2`, `$3`, etc

Comment: Thanks for the answer Please can you help me if hello.php is dynamic file.

Comment: What do you mean by 'dynamic file'? if you have several filenames, you can write `RewriteRule ^/(hello|goodbye|welcome).php$ /folder1/$1.php [L,R=301]`

Comment: dynamic means hello.php can be any file we will not have details about that. Hello.php will be called dynamically by code

Comment: So, *any* php file in the root of the server should be redirected to folder1/<same name> ?

Comment: actually file name pattern will be something -  google.com,yahoo.com but that is parameter and handled in .htaccess